# Quarto RevealJS Header on all slides

Tags: html, css, reveal.js, quarto

I am unable to create a Header on the top left corner of all slides, including the Title slide. I am using `format: revealjs` for the slides.

When using purely `revealjs`, without Quarto, I am able to embed custom `div` class `header` inside the `div class="reveal"`. However, I cannot do so inside Quarto framework since rendering any custom entries inside HTML removes the custom entries.

Any suggestions? Please and thank you!

**Note**: I am aware of the footer options and I am already using the footer for something else, now I need the header.

---

In the pure Reveal.JS, I used the following embedded in the `index.html`:

```html
<div class="reveal">
    <div class="header">
        <section data-markdown="slides/header.md"></section>
    </div>
    <!-- slides in markdown here-->
</div>
```

I have the following inside my `slides/header.md`:

```
Custom header text appears on top left corner of all slides..
```

In order to appears in the top left corner of all slides, I have the following CSS embedded inside `reveal.scss`:

```css
.reveal .header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1em;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

I can not replicate this in Quarto given that the `html` file is modified once I render the `.qmd` file. I also do not know if this "header" can be embedded inside the title parameters of the `.qmd` file.

Current I generate the footer using the following inside my `.qmd` file:

```
format:
    revealjs:
        ...
        footer: "custom footer text"
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have tried for quarto, so that people here can work that and test that out and help you?! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**Update:** I have written a quarto filter extension [`reveal-header`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/reveal-header) to add a header on all slides with `header` option in yaml, so no need to use html file includes explicitly like below.

---

**Old Answer**

You can write javascript code to insert custom div inside the div with class `reveal` in a html file and then refer to that html file within quarto file using `include-after-body` yaml key.

**quarto_revealjs.qmd**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
css: header.css
include-after-body: header_text.html
---


## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a
finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations see
<https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.

## Bullets

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that
includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code
```

**header_text.html**

In this file, we write html code for the div that we want to place inside the div with `reveal` class and then use js code to insert this div element as the first child element of the div with `reveal` class.

```
<div class="header">
    <section>
      Custom header text appears on top left corner of all slides..
    </section>
</div>

<script>
  function add_header() {
    let header = document.querySelector("div.header");
    let reveal = document.querySelector(".reveal");
    reveal.insertBefore(header, reveal.firstChild);
  }
  
  window.onload = add_header();
</script>
```

**header.css**

```
.reveal .header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.3em;
    left: 1em;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    color: gray;
}

.reveal .slides {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

---

[image: title page with a header]

---

[image: next page with that header in top left corner]